# Hot chips - What does the word "hot" mean in this phrase?

Tags: meaning

What does the term **hot chips** mean?

Does the word **hot** mean that they are served hot (referring to their temperature), or rather that they are spicy (or sprinkled with chilli)?

The answers are very appreciated.

**Edit:** I live in a non-English speaking country, saw the term in a book and need to find a term in my local language. The text was on a board which the owner put on their "hot chip stand". I am not sure if the word is used to emphasize the temperature (meaning that they are fresh, just prepared) or a taste variant.

**Edit 2:** The text is in Australian English, i.e. the author refers to French fries (or *pommes frites*). Frankly, I've never seen them with chilly, in our country, they are sold with mustard, ketchup or mayonnaise. On the other hand, they are always sold hot and in my opinion there is no need to emphasize this fact. And this is the reason of my confusion.

Comment: I can imagine a menu distinguishing hot chips from plain chips; but to distinguish hot chips from cold chips seems less likely. What establishment serves cold chips?

Comment: I can't answer your question, because without context I would not know which interpretation is meant. The phrase is not a familiar one to me. Where I live, _chips_ are what the Americans call "fries", so they are normally served hot, and never as far as I know served spicy. (_Chips with curry sauce_ is a thing, but I've never heard it called "hot chips").

Comment: I just found a picture of a 'hot chips stand' (note: 'chips') in an open-air Christmas market in Prague. The article was by an Indian travel writer visiting Europe. What the stand sold was (thermally) hot 'fries' in paper cones. They have thus-named stands in South Africa, Australia and New Zealand that I know of.

Comment: In the UK, you used (before Covid) to see chip stands, booths, vans, etc, at funfairs or the seaside, wherever crowds gather, but I don't think many people said 'hot' at the start, because it is a given that they are so.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I wonder whether the chip stand proprietor was either selling what the Americans call 'chips' (what we call crisps) or was selling what we would call chips (what Americans call 'fries') and wasn't quite sure which dialect of English his customers would speak. Let's face it not many people would want ambient temperature "french fries" but most would find ambient temperature and hot "crisps" totally acceptable. It's also possible that the proprietor was using 'hot' to indicate fresh.

Comment: @BoldBen - I think we need a great deal more context from the OP, which, so far, does not seem to be forthcoming.

Comment: The most likely explanation is the one given in the last sentence of @BoldBen's comment, which is also anticipated in a parenthetical remark at the end of the question itself. The word is not meant to convey the idea that the chips are hot, as opposed to having ambient temperature, but that they are really, really hot, because they are served to the customers immediately after they are made, as opposed to being only lukewarm, as happens when the chips are left standing for some time after being made.

Comment: The OP already knows that  the word *hot* in English has two distinct meanings when applied to food, and that the chips could be hot in either of these two ways. Whether the particular chips in question were hot in one way or the other is something that we can only guess. Some of these guesses may be more plausible than the others, but none of them is likely to illuminate anything about English language and usage.

Comment: It's inherently ambiguous because English doesn't have a special term for "hot (spicy)" chemical "heat" as distinguished from physical "hot". It's a problem for all English speakers unless they're using a special term from a local language, like _pedas_ in Malaysian English or _piquante_ in Latinx English. The rest of us just hafta read the label and see.

Comment: I've edited the post again. The author meant French fries, definitely.

Comment: This has got ridiculous in a way I am coming to recognise. A long tail of comments with one DVed answer. More close votes please! We now (belatedly) hear that the source is Australian. A hot chips stand in Oz is a stand that sells physically hot potato fries. Got it from Google. Voilà, c'est tout.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I'm not Australian but I do know that 'hot' chips in the USA are called "fries" while their 'cold' chips are what the the British call "crisps".  Maybe in Australia they make the same distinction? Maybe the OP could have guessed that the writer was playing with words and their meanings. Maybe the OP could have saved everyone time by mentioning their source from the beginning and supplying the CONTEXT, i.e it's taken from a type of Dr Seuss children's book.

Comment: It's not the first time a user asks a question and says "I read XYZ in a book" or worse "somewhere" but fails to say what kind of book it is  (or where)  and  fails to give its title. Peter Slizik, I don't understand why  you need to remove the image (it's a link?)

Comment: @Mari-LouA - "Australian and New Zealand English uses "chips" both for what North Americans call french fries and for what Britons call crisps. When confusion would occur between the two meanings, "hot chips" and "cold chips" are used." - Wiktionary.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for posting your answers and comments. Frankly, I wouldn't even guess that such a simple question of so dependent on the country where the term is used. And I apologize for not providing enough context at the beginning. I was reluctant to put a photo of two pages on the internet as I wasn't sure how much of the content can be made public without it being considered a copyright infringement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Australian English the word "chips" refers both to deep fried thick strips of potato, normally served fresh and hot and called French fries in US English, and to thin slices of potato cooked until they are crisp, usually bought in packets and called "crisps" in UK English. "Hot chips" especially on a market stand sign would almost always refer to the freshly fried ones. The word "hot" is used on a sign to claim that they are fresh enough to retain their heat.

Note that many Australians distinguish French fries as having a smaller cross section than normal chips.

Also note that the linked picture clearly shows strips, so they are not crisps.

Comment: I will correct my answer appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

It generally means hot as in spicy. This can be seen on the product descriptions of hot chips.

Comment: That depends in whether _chips_ is used in the American or the British sense!

Comment: That's right, but I assumed it was used in an American sense from the context, as I've never seen a french fry stand(British chip) referred to as hot; the additional adjective of "hot" is not usually necessary to describe them. "Hot chip" is commonly used in AmE to refer to a popular food product coated in spicy red coating.

Comment: @Rubrud - South Africa, Australia, and New Zealand are part of the British English zone, and they are happy with 'hot' before 'chip stand', even though the actual Brits in GB might not be.